# Postgres 9.1 - Numbering groups of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data that represents different 'actions'. These 'actions' collectively comprise an 'event'.

The data looks like this:

```
    EventID   |   UserID   |   Action   |        TimeStamp
--------------+------------+------------+-------------------------
       1      |    111     |   Start    |   2012-01-01 08:00:00
       1      |    111     |   Stop     |   2012-01-01 08:59:59
       1      |    999     |   Start    |   2012-01-01 09:00:00
       1      |    999     |   Stop     |   2012-01-01 09:59:59
       1      |    111     |   Start    |   2012-01-01 10:00:00
       1      |    111     |   Stop     |   2012-01-01 10:30:00
```

As you can see, each single 'event' is made of one or more 'Actions' (or as I think of them, 'sub events').

**I need to identify each 'sub event' and give it an identifier.** This is what I am looking for:

```
    EventID   |   SubeventID   |   UserID   |   Action   |        TimeStamp
--------------+----------------+------------+------------+-------------------------
       1      |       1        |    111     |   Start    |   2012-01-01 08:00:00
       1      |       1        |    111     |   Stop     |   2012-01-01 08:59:59
       1      |       2        |    999     |   Start    |   2012-01-01 09:00:00
       1      |       2        |    999     |   Stop     |   2012-01-01 09:59:59
       1      |       3        |    111     |   Start    |   2012-01-01 10:00:00
       1      |       3        |    111     |   Stop     |   2012-01-01 10:30:00
```

I need something that can start counting, but only increment when some column has a specific value (like "Action" = 'Start').

I have been trying to use Window Functions for this, but with limited success. I just can't seem to find a solution that I feel will work... any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any field you can sort by, something like 'ActionTimestamp'? Otherwise, your question is not well defined, as the order of the entries in the table is not clear by definition

Comment: Yes, I have the action timestamp... I'll add that to the question.

Comment: When should the SubEvent change (restart from 1)? Only when the `Action = 'Start'`? Or when the `UserID` changes? Or both?

Comment: "SubeventID" should change when "Action" = 'Start'. It should reset when the "EventID" changes. The "UserID" is a bit tricky as the same person could work on two sequential 'Subevents' (the "SubeventID" should still increment in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have some field you can sort by, you could use the following query (untested):

```
SELECT 
    sum(("Action" = 'Start')::int) OVER (PARTITION BY "EventID" ORDER BY "Timestamp" ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM 
    events
```

Note that if the first SubEvent does not start with Start, it will have an event id of 0, which might not be what you want.

---

You could also use `COUNT()` in place of `SUM()`:

```
SELECT 
    EventID 
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN Action = 'Start' THEN 1 END) 
        OVER ( PARTITION BY EventID 
               ORDER BY TimeStamp 
               ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) 
      AS SubeventID 
  , UserID 
  , Action 
FROM 
    tableX AS t ;
```

Tests at SQL-Fiddle: **[test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2c938/6)**

Comment: I'm getting at error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNBOUNDED"`

Comment: @losthorse: That happens when you do not test the stuff you post. Try now. You probably do not need the `ROWS UNBOUNDED PROCEEDING`, it is just there as I do never remember the standard...

Comment: Okay, that fixed the above error, but now there is a new one: `function sum(boolean) does not exist`

Comment: @losthorse: Alright, fixed that one as well. (In my installation I have defined a custom aggregate `sum(boolean)`, as I use that command often. But casting to `int` should do.

Comment: @ypercube: This is brilliant as well! This is easier for me to understand and your test is perfect... thank you for such a through answer!